# Android service for few activities

Tags: android, android-service

I am trying to create an app with a few activities:

- DashboardActivity
- SettingsActivity
- ....

and with one service (transfer data between the phone and my device).

```
public class MyService extends Service {

....

     public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        int time = intent.getIntExtra(DashboardActivity.PARAM_TIME, 1);
        int task = intent.getIntExtra(DashboardActivity.PARAM_TASK, 0);
        String strMAC = intent.getStringExtra(DashboardActivity.PARAM_MAC);
        String strMESS = intent.getStringExtra(DashboardActivity.PARAM_MESSAGE);

....

}
```

So I can start my service from DashboardActivity. Setup connection, get data.
But I need to get these data when I launch SettingsActivity in SettingActivity.

In my DashboardActivity, I have a broadcast receiver:

```
// create BroadcastReceiver
br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    // действия при получении сообщений
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int task = intent.getIntExtra(PARAM_TASK, 0);
        int status = intent.getIntExtra(PARAM_STATUS, 0);
        //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onReceive: task = " + task + ", status = " + status);

        // looking for start status
        if (status  == STATUS_START) {
            switch (task) {
                case TASK1_CODE:
                    tvTask1.setText("Task1 start" + connectionSTATE);
                    break;
                case TASK2_CODE:
                    tvTask2.setText("Task2 start"+connectionSTATE);
                    break;
                case TASK3_CODE:
                    tvTask3.setText("Task3 start"+connectionSTATE);
                    break;
            }
        }

        // looking for result status
        if (status == STATUS_FINISH) {

            //String result = intent.getStringExtra(PARAM_RESULT);
            int[] result = intent.getIntArrayExtra(PARAM_RESULT);
            switch (task) {
                case TASK1_CODE:
                    tvTask1.setText("Task1 finish, result = " + Arrays.toString(result)+" "+connectionSTATE);
                    break;
                case TASK2_CODE:
                    tvTask2.setText("Task2 finish, result = " + Arrays.toString(result)+" "+connectionSTATE);
                    break;
                case TASK3_CODE:
                    tvTask3.setText("Task3 finish, result = " + Arrays.toString(result) + " " + connectionSTATE);
                    myView.setLabelText(Arrays.toString(result));
                    //String message =Integer.toHexString(result[1]);
                   onClicksent_data(Integer.toHexString(result[1]));
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
};
// Filter BroadcastReceiver
IntentFilter intFilt = new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_ACTION);
// turnOn BroadcastReceiver
registerReceiver(br, intFilt);
```

How can I do that in SettingsActivity?

How can I send a task to one service from different activities and resive data to these activities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to create a app using a container Activity with different fragments, and I put the registion of broadcast and broadcastreceiver in this container activity, so that my fragments can share this broadcastreceiver. But, I should start my service before my registion of broadcast in my activity or start it by system outside of the app.

What I want to say is, you should design your data structure. If you want your activities in your app to share one broadcastreceiver, I suggest you to put this starting service, registion of broadcast and broadcastreceiver and so on in your manifest.

Comment: I find another way. It more easy for me, to use ViewFlipper)) But thank you! i ll try to use your suggestion in future!